# 3 column, fixed header, sidebars fixed, content scrollable

Tags: css, html, layout

Can anyone assist me with the following div layout? I have tried a couple of solutions, however, the only way i have been able to accomplish this is using tables.

[image: site layout]

I had a look at [Holy Grail 3 Column Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm), however, this layoyt is not 100% height, and header is not fixed, i also need only the content to scroll, the sidebars needs to be fixed 100% height

Comment: Try bootstrap scaffolding. It's a great universal solution.

Comment: By height:100% on the 3 columns under the top black header, you mean 100%-50px right? And do you need the scroll-bar to be on the middle (white) column or you want the page to be scrollable (scroll-bar on the side of the page) and the white column scroll with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the answers here ignored most of your requirements. I stumbled upon this because I am having a rendering issue with the same layout you are after. I forked the fiddle above to show you:

http://jsfiddle.net/RsRf9/2/

The major difference is that the entire body is scrollable, not just the tiny area in the center (I think this is what you are after).

Aside from cleaning up styles that weren't doing anything (like floats while position fixed), the major change is to the center col - all you should need is this:

```
.center{margin:100px 200px;}
```

The other change is how you get that "height 100%" effect on your sidebars - my trick is to do this:

```
.left,.right{width:200px;top: 100px; bottom: 0px;position: fixed;}
```

Instead of height 100%, I simply tell it to stretch from top 100 (the bottom of the nav) to bottom 0 (the bottom of the page)

That will push the content bellow the top nav and in between your two fixed side bars.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I'm a few years late on marking it as the answer though.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a working fiddle as per your requirements:

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DA3s/8/) - UPDATED to include fixed header ONLY TOP BAR IS FIXED

The important thing to note is the structural layout of the divs... notice that the .center is AFTER the .right

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='head'>Header</div>
    <div class='bodywrap'>
        <div class='left'>left</div>
        <div class='right'>right</div>
        <div class='center'>center center center center center center center center center center center center ... blah</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the css is:

JUST HEADER FIXED:

```
html,body{height:100%}
.wrap{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative}
.head{height:100px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%} << UPDATED for fixed header
.bodywrap{margin-top:100px;width:102%;margin-left:-1%} << UPDATED - Terrible hack and you may find something more elegant
.left,.right{width:200px;height:100%}
.left,.center,.right,.bodywrap{height:100%}
.left{float:left;}
.center{margin-left:200px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;}
.right{float:right;}

.left{background-color:#aaa}
.right{background-color:#ccc}
.center{background-color:#444}
.head{background-color:#777}
```

HEADER AND SIDEBARS FIXED (Also was able to fix dirty hack for .left and .right undersizing

```
html,body{height:100%}
.wrap{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative}
.head{height:100px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%}
.bodywrap{margin-top:100px;margin-left:-8px}
.left,.right{width:200px;height:100%}
.left,.center,.right,.bodywrap{height:100%}
.left{float:left;position:fixed}
.center{margin-left:200px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;margin-right:191px}
.right{position:fixed;right:0}

.left{background-color:#aaa}
.right{background-color:#ccc}
.center{background-color:#444}
.head{background-color:#777}
```

[Here is with top and sides fixed center scroll liquid center column](http://jsfiddle.net/6DA3s/9/) (and no gaps on .left and .right)

It's basic use of floats but the structural markup layout is key ;)

Comment: OOh just noticed the fixed position of the header... give me a few mins

Comment: There is a problem with the width of the three columns - notice how the .left,.right have a ~6px gap left and right? I think thats to do with the scrollbar in the .center

Comment: added terrible hack to fix the undersized .left and .right - updated answer and fiddle

Comment: this is fairly close, how do i get the left and right columns to remain static and not scroll with the center column?

Comment: The dirty hack is not without it's problems @DustyRoberts - I'll have a ponder / ask a SO question as to why this might be happening. I'll update with fixed position left and right columns if I can... one minute

Comment: @DustyRoberts - Updated (see at bottom) but now trying to sort out the scrollbars... do you want the scrollbar on the page or the div?

Comment: scrollbars sorted (so just scrollbar in div) fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6DA3s/10/

Comment: (in other words @DustyRoberts I have my own work to be getting out of bed for :P)

Comment: @paulSullivan - again. Kudos for that solution. It's hard to make that work. No discredit from me. But the OPs request for mixed fixed/proportional is not without it's problems as I know you're aware. I cringe when the page is brought down below 400px width. Perhaps it's just me. You deserve the answer credit here, but I couldn't possibly prostitute myself to succumb to such a layout :)

Comment: @cirrus thanks for kudos :) I don't particularly care about the answer credit (would be nice though) but yours IS the preferred layout (though I prefer `ems` and `body{font-size:62.49%}` method personally because it's easier to convert to px i.e. 1em = 10px). Just hope it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [YUI grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) style sheet for this kind of layout. It is tried and tested and works in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy to do in a rudimentary sense, you don't need tables (or table-cell) but mixing px and % sizes can be problematic. If you stick to % your page will resize better anyway. Handling the cross browser issues takes a bit more CSS tweaking, but there are plenty of grid solutions out there that implement tried and tested solutions even for IE6 and frameworks like twitter's bootstrap will offer a lot more on top.

In other words, this is a solved problem, but here's a quick example of how you can get there by hand;

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    header
</div>

<div class="left">
left
</div>

<div class="main">
    content
</div>

<div class="right">
    right
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS;

```
html, body, .container
{
height:100%;
}

.container
{
background-color: pink;
}

.header
{
background-color: yellow;
height:50px;
}

.left
{
background-color: red;
float:left;
width:10%;
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.right
{
background-color: blue;
float:left;
width:10%;
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.main
{
background-color:#fefefe;
float:left;
height:100%;
width: 80%;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

And of course the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMuE9/)

Using % sizing will also allow you to approach a more responsive design that works for tablet and mobile. Again, many of the grid frameworks out there are 'responsive' in design.

Comment: but this doesn't address the fixed width left and right columns. That's one of the harder parts to do.

Comment: Fair enough. If the OP is set on those for some reason. @Paul Sullivan has that answer for you. Personally, I believe px sizing is evil. If the OP wants a solution that works for various screen sizes (mobile, ipad etc) he can come back to my answer. You can have a +1 from me.

Comment: Yes it may well be that % is responsive BUT the op requested fixed left and right columns

Comment: Yup agreed but the poster has a specific question :) Yours is the more 'correct' method of doing this layout but clients can be funny task masters

Comment: True. Good Job. +1 for that.

Comment: responsive seems to be the trend lately, however, i believe browsers on the various media devices are quite capeable of rendering content as it was intended, thanx for the answer though.

Comment: You're right. Mobile browsers certainly do a lot of work to make sure pages render appropriately for the intended screen space. iPad to name one. But are you suggesting that we no longer need to care? Surely that would only be true if every laptop, desktop, pad and phone were all of the same dimensions (or reported dimensions - as per iPad). True responsive designs are fashionable, but fixed width pages are a hangup from the 90s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollToFixed plugin for left-sidebar and right-sidebar fixed and center column content only scroll up side and downside.
For demo scroll use below link
http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

And one more thing use Bootstrap for design UI.
Include Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript in your page header part

```html
  <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="col-md-3" id="left-sidebar">
                 left-content
             <div>
             <div class="col-md-6" id="center">
                 center content
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3" id="right-sidebar">
                 right-content
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

You can modify as per your requirement. I just give you general hint.

Just write below script for scrolling

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#right-sidebar').scrollToFixed({
                        marginTop: function() {
                            return 5;
                        },
                        limit: function() {
                            return (
                                 $('#footer-widgets-bg').offset().top - $('#right-sidebar').outerHeight(true)
                            );
                        },
                        zIndex: 1,
                        removeOffsets: true
                    });  
    });
```